# DB2 dynamic table name

Tags: sql, database, db2

I want to count the rows of a number of tables. But the table name should be used dynamically. I want to do that within one SQL statement.

I tried it with

```
BEGIN ATOMIC 
  FOR tmp AS (
    SELECT tabschema || '.' || tabname tbl 
    FROM syscat.tables WHERE tabname LIKE '%CD') DO 
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tmp.tbl); 
  END FOR; 
END
```

but I receive the error

```
DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not a 
valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it returned:
SQL0204N  "TMP.TBL" is an undefined name.  LINE NUMBER=1.  SQLSTATE=42704
```

and found no other working solution...

Is there a solution for that?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tmp.tbl` should translate in multiple statements like

```
select count(*) from TABLECD
select count(*) from TABLE2CD
...
```

However, your query will try to do a count of the table TBL in the schema TMP.

You'll have to prepare the complete SQL statement, store it in a variable and pass it to the PREPARE statement ([documentation](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.1.0/com.ibm.db2.udb.admin.doc/doc/r0000975.htm?lang=en) ).

A rather complete stored procedure which somewhat fits your requirements can be found [here](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1036855) . The result of the counts will be stored in a table `COUNTERS` which you can query afterwards.

//edit: this is the example from the topic, adapt to work (not tested since I have no DB2 instance to test atm):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE tableCount()
LANGUAGE SQL
BEGIN
   DECLARE SQLCODE INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
   DECLARE SQLSTATE CHAR(5);
   DECLARE vTableName VARCHAR(20);
   DECLARE vTableCount INTEGER;
   DECLARE stmt varchar(2000);
   DECLARE not_found CONDITION FOR SQLSTATE '02000';
   DECLARE c1 CURSOR FOR
   SELECT tabname from syscat.tables where tabschema='DB2ADMIN';
   DECLARE C2 CURSOR FOR S2
   DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR not_found
   SET stmt = '';
   Delete from COUNTERS;
   OPEN c1;
   getRows:
   LOOP
     FETCH c1 INTO vTableName;
     IF SQLCODE = 0 THEN
       SET stmt ='SELECT Count(*) FROM ' ||  vTableName;
       PREPARE S2 FROM stmt;
       OPEN C2;
       SET vTableCount = 0;
       FETCH C2 INTO vTableCount;
       INSERT INTO COUNTERS (tableName, tableCount)
              VALUES (vTableName, vTableCount);
       CLOSE C2;
     ELSE
       LEAVE getRows;
     END IF;
   END LOOP getRows;
   CLOSE c1;
END
```

Comment: I always get this error: DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not a 
valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it returned:
SQL0104N  An unexpected token "PREPARE" was found following "ame LIKE '%CD') 
DO  ".  Expected tokens may include:  "SELECT".  LINE NUMBER=5.  
SQLSTATE=42601

Comment: I added the code from the linked forum topic with the needed corrections. I can't test it though. 
Don't forget that the 'PREPARE' statement must be run inside a stored procedure.